# if statement to print a statement based on the output of a random choice function with a string array

Tags: arrays, random

I am not able to refer to an output of a random choice function using an array.

```
import random
dice = ["•", "• •", "• • •", "• • • •", "• • • • •", "• • • • • •"] #strings of dots

print(random.choice(dice))

if dice == dice([5]): #Does not work, not able to refer to the six dot string

     print("You are lucky.")

elif dice:
     print("You are not lucky.")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:-

You can compare String length and if it is equal to 5, then u can print the statements

```
import random
dice = ["•", "• •", "• • •", "• • • •", "• • • • •", "• • • • • •"] #strings of dots

randomDiceChoice = random.choice(dice)

if len(randomDiceChoice) == 5: 

    print("You are lucky.")

elif dice:
    print("You are not lucky.")
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. For six dots, it would be 11 then.

Comment: @FIREREED you can mark this as answer if this post helped you. Thanks a lot :)